# What is best way to read CSV data?

Tags: csv, connection-string, oledb, c#-2.0

I am using C# and trying to read a `CSV` by using this connection string;

> ```
> Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\rajesh.yadava\Desktop\orcad;Extended  Properties="Text;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;FMT=Delimited"
> ```

This works for tab delimited data.

I want a connection string which should for tab delimited as well as comma(,) and pipe(|).

How can I make a generic connection string for `CSV`.

Thanks
Rajesh

Answer (score 2):

Is the [filehelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) library an option?

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't answer your questions, but here's a word of warning.

I've had to create my own reader as you don't get the correct drivers if you ever run on a 64 bit system.

If your software will ever run on a 64 bit system, make sure you test it first and that the oledb or odbc drivers will be present.

Answer (score 1):

In case that you need a fast sequential access to the CSV file, the [Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) could be an option. I have used it on a project some time ago with great success. It is supposed to be optimized quite well and also provides a cached version, if you need it. Additionally, it was updated several times since it was first released back in 2005 (last update in 2008-10-09) and it supports basic databinding by implementing `System.Data.IDataReader`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few links from the net discussing this issue:

- [Manipulating CSV Files](http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2003/10/01/29964.aspx)
- [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/?carrier=textfile)
- [How To Open Delimited Text Files Using the Jet Provider's Text IIsam](http://support.microsoft.com:80/support/kb/articles/Q262/5/37.ASP)

Answer (score 0):

Is using the TextFieldParser class an option?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Without rolling a custom solution, I'm not sure there's a straightforward way to support more than one delimiter. [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353.aspx) suggests that through schema.ini you can choose between:

- TabDelimited
- CSVDelimited
- one specific character (except double quote)
- fixed width

Answer (score 0):

```
    class CSVFile extends SplFileObject
{

private $keys;

    public function __construct($file)
    {
        parent::__construct($file);
        $this->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        parent::rewind();
        $this->keys = parent::current();
        parent::next();
    }

    public function current()
    {
        return array_combine($this->keys, parent::current());
    }

    public function getKeys()
    {
        return $this->keys;
    }
}
```

then use with:

```
$csv = new CSVFile('exmaple.csv');
```

and you can iterate through lines using:

```
foreach ($csv as $line)
{
```